# How to use Redux forms for highly nested subcomponents?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form, react-state-management

I have recently started working on react-redux application and came across bit of complex form to implement like below. I have modularized application by creating granular components.  -

[image]

I want to store whole state of this form in a redux because the state should be persisted across back and forward button clicks throughout the application. I read through couple of online articles on redux-forms and Formik. Looking at the complexity and storage requirements, redux-forms seems to be right fit for my application. However I am still not sure whether I would be able to successfully implement form logic with redux-forms as I have got many nested sub-components which can be seen in image above. Can someone guide me how to go about integrating redux-forms for nested sub-components? Would Redux-form's Form-section be a right choice for 3-4 levels of component nesting?

Comment: Connect those components directly to redux

Comment: I want to maintain current pattern of connecting to Redux only though Container-component which is the top most component in image above

Comment: Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose if you're going to just be passing the state down 4 or 5 layers?  You could just wrap these nested components in containers and hook them up as needed

Comment: Thanks @danny-buonocore for your inputs. If I connect the redux store directly to containers of nested components, then I don't really need redux-form because I can't have form declaration in each container. Is that right? Also is it bad practice to pass state down 4-5 layers?

Comment: I can't comment on your question about redux form, but if you are using redux, it is _very bad_ practice to repeatedly pass down props. It makes your components harder to reason, forces coupling between components, gives props to components that don't need it, can slow down your app (sometimes substantially) and makes it very hard to switch around the component hierarchy (a consequence of coupling).